# What is different between .dll and .DLL

Tags: dll, windows-installer

I'm using MSI to create a setup, it's all fine but I have a question that I got this:
[image]

Why do we get .dll and .DLL file? And what is the difference between them.
Thanks

Comment: Looks like this setup wizard floundered when it auto-detected the dependencies.  Not entirely unusual, .NET assemblies don't have a fixed extension.  It is rather flaky tool, it was removed from VS for a good reason.  You need to remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

There's no difference between them, just that the creator of the name and extension chose to name them that way. The Operating system considers them the same types of files. Same thing happens with .EXE and .exe, .AVI, .... Some organizations may consider it a naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

On a Windows filesystem, there is absolutely no difference as file names are case insensitive.

The only time you will notice a problem is when accessing the filesystem through a file sharing protocol that is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

That screenshot is Visual Studio Deployment Projects view and it appears it isn't smart enough to realize those are the same DLL's.  I'd build the MSI and look at it in ORCA and see if it actually tried to package it twice and create a component rule violation in the process.  It wouldn't surprise me at all but this isn't one of well known issues that I can recall at the moment.

In addition to Windows being case aware but case insensitive, fill extensions don't really matter that much either.  A Windows dynamically loaded library (PE format)  can be any extension as the LoadLibrary() function doesn't really care.  Common extensions are .DLL, .SYS, .OCX and .DRV.